# Why does my image link convert to base 64 automatically in visual studio code?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web-scraping, puppeteer

These are the queries I use to fetch the image src in the browser console and I get the desired output:

```
let logoLink = document.querySelector('div[class="jsx-1935571144 college-info d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center"] > a[class="jsx-1935571144 logo bg-white pointer-none"] > img');
logoLink.getAttribute('src').toString();
```

OUTPUT :

```
https://images.static-collegedunia.com/public/college_data/images/logos/149154157555.jpg?tr=h-80,w-80,c-force
```

However, when I run the same query in a `.js` file in visual studio code, The link is transformed to base64.

OUTPUT:

```
data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAHd3dwAAACH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==
```

And this doesn't give me the image I want. Is there a way to convert this back to an image, I couldn't find any online that work?

Answer (score 0):

That IS your image.  It's just BASE64-encoded.  If you run that string through a base64 decoder, you'll see it starts GIF89a, which is the magic sequence for a GIF.  You just need to decode it.